# Constant data polling for web view from database

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, web

we're working on a solution that must have a dashboard with some basic views/charts that whenever active should get updated every 10 seconds or so, and each user might have the same charts but displaying filtered information.
To have this implemented, I started looking into push technologies and began doing some tests with JSF + PrimeFaces + PrimePush. 
It does the job of refreshing the view, but in the backend, I have to make a pretty solid structure with scheduled jobs and session management that takes care of getting the information from the database at the expected rate. Also, since PrimePush is working with Atmosphere, the channel concept might be a problem, as every user will need a different channel for the "data feed".

The point I'm trying to get here, is to get opinions on how appropiate this approach might be and if there are any known alternatives (Java related ones, please) that could be a better fit for a dashboard scenario.

Thanks a lot for your time and if anyone needs more information, I'm more than glad to provide it.

Comment: being lazy I would just go for a jquery setInterval and ajax call to a servlet

Comment: That will make a bunch of requests probably saturating the network and sometimes even for nothing, because there might not be changes in the data. Any other thoughts? Thanks a lot for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency is not really high: 10s is quite a long polling interval.

In that case polling from the browser using AJAX is fine.
As for the backend, the servlet could query a database for the last changes.

That's a simple setup, but it should be good enough.

If you experienced performance problems, you could consider asynchronous servlets together with JMS queues. This would be appropriate, if the latency should be smaller (500ms for example).